# Pytorch .to('cuda') or .cuda() doesn't work and just get stuck

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to do pytorch tutorial. When I try to set their device as cuda, it does not work and my code running get stuck.

For specific information, I am using conda environment of 
python 3.7.3
pytorch 1.3.0
cuda 10.2 (NVIDIA RTX2080TI)

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
>>> torch.cuda.device_count()
1
>>> torch.cuda.current_device()
0
>>> device = torch.device('cuda:0')
>>> device
device(type='cuda', index=0)
>>> aa = torch.randn(5)
>>> aa = tensor([-2.2084, -0.2700, 0.0921, -1.7678, 0.7642])
>>> aa.to(device)


nothing happens...
```

Can anybody please help me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: even in `pytorch--->>1.4.0-py3.6_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has happened with the Pytorch 1.3.0 release (the release was this week). I too face this bug. Basically, when I call `.to(device)`, it just hangs and does nothing.

If you would like to fix this temporarily, you can downgrade to PyTorch 1.2.0. To do this, I ran:

```
conda install pytorch=1.2.0 torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

I would have just commented but I do not have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: Thanks Relh! I found that pytorch 1.2.0 doesn't have cudatoolkit of 10.2, but however I installed cuda 10.0 and pytorch 1.2.0 and it works perfectly! I sincerely appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

`GeForce 30` series need `cuda 11 =<` , so try to use cuda 11 =< using,

```
conda install pytorch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 torchaudio==0.8.0 cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```