# Model.to(‘cuda:0’) gets stuck

Tags: pytorch, pycharm

I'm using:

```
python 3.8.10

torch                1.11.0+cu113
```

And:

```
NVIDIA-SMI 470.103.01   Driver Version: 470.103.01   CUDA Version: 11.4
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

I can run the following commands via `jupyter notebook` with not error:

```
out = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
mX = mX.to(out)
```

When I try to run those commands from `pycharm` (with same `virtual environment`), nothing happens and it gets stuck.

I looked here:

> [Pytorch .to('cuda') or .cuda() doesn't work and just get stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58344480/pytorch-tocuda-or-cuda-doesnt-work-and-just-get-stuck)
> and didn't found any answer.

1. Why I can use `to('cuda')` from `jupyter notebook` and not from `pycharm` ?
2. What do I need to do in order to run from `pycharm` ?

Comment: what do you mean "nothing happens"? is it the `torch.cuda.is_available()` call that is non-terminating? can you call other parts of `torch.cuda`?

Comment: its gets stuck.